# Get Linux Executable Signing Certificate Information

Tags: executable, certificates, binary

I wanted to know if there was a way (some sort of library that I'm unaware of) that gets the signing certificate details of an executable. I know it's possible to sign a binary using `openssl` but how can I retrieve this details? In mac there is a command called `codesign` that allows getting details of signed packages/executables.  Is there something similar to this on linux?